# MEF Import ins null unless you put breakpoints in the code

Tags: c#, mef

I am using MEF on a project but am having a nightmare for it to resolve the imports when running the application.

It states that the object is null and throws an exception error.

If i debug the application locally and put breakpoints it resolves. Seems like its not resolving when opening the application.

Below is my MEF Resolver class which is initiaited from global.asax

```
public class MEFDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public MEFDependencyResolver()
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer
        (
            new AggregateCatalog
            (
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                         .GetAssemblies()
                         .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("T20Cricket2014"))
                         .Select(a => new AssemblyCatalog(a))
            )
        );
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return GetType().GetMethods().First(m => m.IsGenericMethod && m.Name == "GetService").MakeGenericMethod(serviceType).Invoke(this, null);
    }
    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            var export = container.GetExport<T>();
            return export == null ? default(T) : export.Value;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return new object[0];
    }

    readonly CompositionContainer container;
}
```

here is one of my classes which fails on load of the application:

```
[Export]
public class DefaultBuilder
{
    [Import]
    public IUserData Users;

    public Default Build(string ID)
    {

        var user = Users.Get(ID);
        var isNull = user == null;
        return new Default
        {
            Registered = user != null,
            User = isNull ? null : user.Name
        };
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is due to stability issue with MEF or I have done something wrong.

Comment: Does it work even if you don't examine any values while execution is paused on the breakpoint? I've had something like this happen because I examined an object while the code was paused, the debugger caused a lazy loaded value to be loaded, so everything worked while I was debugging.

Comment: That is what you call a Heisenbug..

Comment: Will have a look because the generic method might be lazy loaded. Sometimes it works when examining the values whilst debugging and hitting the breakpoints other times it does not.

Comment: I have changed the solution to MVC rather than webapi and it works fine now.